# Div text vertical padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've noticed that as fonts get larger and larger, the vertical padding in a div element above and below the text grows larger. Is there anyway quick way to prevent this? Is this font dependent?

I'm attempting to create a word cloud, but these vertical spacings are proving to be quite annoying.

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the line-height is your answer but I would recommend the em unit and setting the line-height to 1em for all font sizes in your tag cloud. I always use em's to represent line-height because regardless of whether the font is set by pixels, ems, or some other unit, line-height is always relative to the size of the font.

According the the W3C specification for line-height

> A value of 'normal' sets the 'line-height' to a reasonable value for
>   the element's font. It is suggested that UAs set the 'normal' value to
>   be a number in the range of 1.0 to 1.2.

This means the font size can vary but the vertical height of the fonts will always remain consistent and relative to the corresponding size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `line-height` style rule to change the amount of space around the text

Comment: I don't like using the word *padding* in this context as I think it's really misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your css:

```
line-height: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could research for some already done word clouds.

Or just put classes to the different sizes, and so you can put negative padding to the bigger sized words.

```
.span bigger {
    font-size:2 em;
    padding: -4px;
}
.span big {
    font-size:1.5 em;
    padding: -2px;
}
.span small {
    font-size:0.9 em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope it helped or at least gave you some cool ideas! ;)